# .NET primitive type addition oddities?

Tags: c#, double, overflow, int, primitive

I was curious, so I ran a couple of tests to see how .NET handles overflow (I couldn't find it documented anywhere). I'd almost wish they spit out overflow errors instead of the results because honestly these results are just bizarre:

1. `Int32.MaxValue + Int32.MaxValue = -2`
   I understand that it wraps around, but why do that instead of throwing an OverflowException? Isn't that what "unchecked" is for... to ignore overflows? I'm kind of baffled as to what unchecked is for now, especially since I've seen it used for creating hash values.
2. `Double.PositiveInfinity + Double.NegativeInfinity = Double.NaN`
   Another oddity. 1 + -1 = 0. 100 + -100 = 0. So why is Infinity + -Infinity = NaN?
3. `Double.PositiveInfinity / Double.PositiveInfinity = Double.NaN`
   Again, why the oddity? I'd figure this should be 1 or possibly 0 (b/c the limit of x / Infinity = 0). In fact... `Double.MaxValue / Double.PositiveInfinity = 0` ...
4. `Double.PositiveInfinity / 0 = Infinity`
   What!? No DivideByZeroException!?
5. `Double.MaxValue + Double.MaxValue = Infinity`
   Yea, this one does not throw an OverflowException, but also does NOT wrap around? So I guess not all primitive types behave like int does. Oddly enough, I can do things such as `Double.MaxValue + 1 = 1.79769313486232E+308`. So adding beyond the MaxValue of a double is possible (probably loses precision?), but after some unknown number (it can probably be figured out - or has already) it loses its ability to display a valid number and gives back Infininty?

Well, the rest is kind of repetitive. I'm just wondering why these operate the way they do? Especially the Double operators. It was very unexpected for me to be able to add beyond the MaxValue.

Comment: #1 is controlled by a build setting in Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced... -> Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow.  Use of Checked/Unchecked just overrides this setting to say "always check/don't check this code for overflow/underflow".

Comment: @Adam and by the checked/unchecked keywords, for more localised usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes; `checked` will fix that; `unchecked` is the default behaviour
2. Mathematically, you can't add +inf and -inf, and you can't infer a sign. NaN is the only sane option; however, +inf + +inf => +inf, and -inf + -inf => -inf, like you might deduce
3. Again, mathematically that first work. Not least, it would lead to 2*x/x=>1, which would be worse. But basically : inf is not a number
4. No, they don't; that is the expected behaviour for floating point
5. Float doesn't wrap; <s>exceeding max is infinity</s>

Comment: But in #5, Exceeding Max isn't Infinity (until a certain point, which I don't know) as shown by simply adding 1.

Comment: +1 is too small to change the value of the number.  Double.MaxValue + 1 = Double.MaxValue.  To get inifinity, you'd have to add something large enough to affect the final digit in the number.

Comment: I can't tell you off the top of my head.  You'd have to dig into the definition of the double precision type.

Comment: @michael: In regards to #5, see this article (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/overflow_checking.aspx) which states : In fact, overflow in floating point numbers (float and double) will never throw an exception but simply return a special value of +/- Infinity. On the other hand, for the decimal type, the checked/unchecked keywords are also ignored but overflow always throws an OverflowException.

Comment: @0A0D: So decimal is different than float not just in terms of precision.

Comment: @Michael to make it more confusing - int / float addition (etc) is an IL operation, so int can observe checked (different IL). Decimal is a static operator, so can't.

Answer (score 5):

#### About 2/3

Infinity isn't a number. It doesn't act like a number, either.

If we let `a` be the number of positive integers (1, 2, 3, ...), `b` be the number of even integers (2, 4, 6, ...), and `c` be the number of odd integers (1, 3, 5, ...). It's pretty clear that both `a`, `b` and `c` are infinity.

You would probably expect that `a - a = 0`, which means in this case `infinity - infinity = 0`. However, you could also expect `a - b = c`, since `c` are the numbers in `a`, which are not in `b`. This, however, gives us that `infinity - infinity = infinity`.

By constructing your infinities correctly, you could produce any integer as the answer for `infinity - infinity`. Therefore, it makes no sense to give it a proper definition, so we let it be `NaN`, or "Not a Number".

The same goes for division, which is point 3.

Comment: But, Double isn't a set of numbers. It's a single number.

Comment: Yes, but `a`, `b` and `c` are the sizes of the sets, not the sets themselves.